# How does $\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-1}p$ become $(1-p)^m p \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^k$?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, summation

What sum rules are applied from line 1 to 2 below? I get the constant rule in regard to $p$, but that's about it.

$$\begin{align}
P(X > m) &= \sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-1}p \tag{1}\\
&= (1-p)^m p \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^k \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

This is from my text book, I'm asking because the book doesn't note the rules used.

Comment: factorization by $p(1-p)^m$.

Comment: Consider distributive law

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

$$\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-1}p = (1-p)^mp+(1-p)^{m+1}p+(1-p)^{m+2}p+ \dots =$$
$$(1-p)^mp \cdot[1+(1-p)+(1-p)^2+ \dots = (1-p)^mp\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^k $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}p(1-p)^{k-1}=p(1-p)^m\sum_{(k-m-1)=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)^{k-1}}{(1-p)^m}=$$

$$p(1-p)^m\sum_{(k-m-1)=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-m-1}=p(1-p)^m\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^{t}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a change of variable, let $l=k-(m+1)$, when $k=m+1$, $l=0$.

That is $k= l+(m+1)$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty (1-p)^{k-1}p &= (1-p)^mp\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty (1-p)^{k-1-m}\\
&=(1-p)^mp\sum_{l=0}^\infty (1-p)^{l+(m+1)-(1+m)}\\
&=(1-p)^mp\sum_{l=0}^\infty (1-p)^{l}\\
\end{align}